# Construction of a class with task property in Ada 2005

Tags: class, ada

I have a class `Test_Class` in Ada 2005 which has a parent-linked task property called Primary, from type Primary_Task, defined as:

```
   type Test_Class is tagged limited
      record
         Info    : Integer;
         Value   : Float;
         Primary : Primary_Task (Test_Class'Access);
      end record;
```

I need build a one-step constructor for my class in the form

```
   function Construct (T : access Test_Class) return Test_Class_Ptr is
   begin
      return new Test_Class'(Info => T.Info + 1,
                             Value => 0.0,
                             Primary => [WHAT I WANNA KNOW]);
   end Construct;
```

Currently my code is:

```
-- test_pkg.ads
package Test_Pkg is
   type Test_Class;
   type Test_Class_Ptr is access all Test_Class;

   task type Primary_Task (This_Test : access Test_Class) is
      pragma Storage_Size (1000);
   end Primary_Task;

   type Test_Class is tagged limited
      record
         Info    : Integer;
         Value   : Float;
         Primary : Primary_Task (Test_Class'Access);
      end record;

   function Construct (T : access Test_Class) return Test_Class_Ptr;
end Test_Pkg;

-- test_pkg.adb
with Text_IO; use Text_IO;
package body Test_Pkg is
   [...]

   function Construct (T : access Test_Class) return Test_Class_Ptr is
      T_Ptr : constant Test_Class_Ptr := new Test_Class;
   begin
      T_Ptr.Info := T.Info + 1;
      T_Ptr.Value := 0.0;
      return T_Ptr;
   end Construct;
end Test_Pkg;
```

So, how can I code it? What should I put in `Primary => [...]` code? Should I change the definition of `Primary : Primary_Task (Test_Class'Access);` in `Test_Class` definition?

Comment: can you provide some more information on what you are trying to achieve ? Have you read this : http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Tasking

Comment: I do think you should wait for an answer on comp.lang.ada before asking here as well (or vice versa, of course)! Randy Brukardt's answer there was good.

Comment: @SimonWright, I guess Randy is right. Before making the question I tried to use this same solution (which is like one suggestion you gave me some posts ago in comp.lang.ada), but the problem fortunately was not the code. Now I realize that the problem may be a GNAT BUG from GPL 2011 version. Since at home I just use the GPL compiler, I could never use it with success before. But maybe gnatpro clears it, shall gonna test it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from Randy Brukardt (thank you) on comp.lang.ada:

> In Ada 2005 or later, use "<>" to default initialize a component in an
>   aggregate (which is the only thing you can do with a task).
>
> (...)

```
function Construct (T : access Test_Class) return Test_Class_Ptr is
begin
 return new Test_Class'(Info => T.Info + 1,
                       Value => 0.0,
                       Primary => <>);
end Construct;
```

However, I tried to compile it using GNAT GPL 2011 and got the GNATBUG below

```
c:\tst>gnatmake -gnat12 test_pkg.adb
gcc -c -gnat12 test_pkg.adb

+===========================GNAT BUG DETECTED==============================+
| GPL 2011 (20110428) (i686-pc-mingw32) GCC error:                         |
| in create_tmp_var, at gimplify.c:505                                     |
| Error detected around test_pkg.adb:20:29                          |
| Please submit a bug report by email to report@adacore.com.               |
| GAP members can alternatively use GNAT Tracker:                          |
| http://www.adacore.com/ section 'send a report'.                         |
| See gnatinfo.txt for full info on procedure for submitting bugs.         |
| Use a subject line meaningful to you and us to track the bug.            |
| Include the entire contents of this bug box in the report.               |
| Include the exact gcc or gnatmake command that you entered.              |
| Also include sources listed below in gnatchop format                     |
| (concatenated together with no headers between files).                   |
| Use plain ASCII or MIME attachment.                                      |
+==========================================================================+
Please include these source files with error report
Note that list may not be accurate in some cases,
so please double check that the problem can still
be reproduced with the set of files listed.
Consider also -gnatd.n switch (see debug.adb).

test_pkg.adb
test_pkg.ads

raised TYPES.UNRECOVERABLE_ERROR : comperr.adb:423
gnatmake: "test_pkg.adb" compilation error
```

So GNAT GPL users may have to wait for the next release to use this solution.